How to ask for clarification when I lack the reputation to do so?
I'd like to ask BertR for clarification regarding his answer to this question. However, I don't have enough reputation to comment. The guidelines say I shouldn't submit an answer that is really a request for clarification, so what should I do? Also, I'm pretty sure I shouldn't even be asking this question here, but can't find a suitable place to ask questions like this. I don't have enough reputation for chat either, so I can't ask in there.

What do you want to ask?

Actually, I thought another source contradicted a couple of your examples, but as I  checked them to answer you here, it became clear that I had just confused a couple of characters. All clear now. Thanks for the offer though.

Yes, this is the right place to ask these types of questions.
The reason for restrictions on this site is to encourage involvement in the site which is supposed to help you understand and appreciate the site.
It prevents new users from jumping on the site and participating without first taking the time to have a look around at how things work.
You can see the different privileges available and what amount of reputation you need to reach those levels by looking here https://chinese.stackexchange.com/privileges
The hardest part is usually the first 100 points, this is usually because new users want to jump in and do everything straight away. But it isn't that hard to get there.
The easiest way for you to get your first 100 points:

Provide suggested edits by looking at other people's messy posts and making a significant improvement with style, structure or grammar etc. Note, small, insignificant edits are usually ignored
Provide a good quality answer to another persons question that is likely to attract up votes
Ask good quality questions. Good questions only get rewarded with half as many points as good quality answers and the site only want questions that are worthwhile, good quality and are based on a real problem that someone would have. So it is not recommended to ask questions just to get reputation, but if you can think of something interesting to ask this is still a way for you to build your reputation.

Welcome to the site and I hope you enjoy your time here and get to find your way round quickly!
If you have any more issues please feel free to ask them here on meta or in chat.

Thanks for the clarifications. And now I can upvote!
